# Unable to view a table on redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
import psycopg2
import os

host = 'xxxx.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com'
db_name = 'dev'
user = 'awsuser' 
password = 'xxxx' 
port = '5439'

conn = psycopg2.connect("host={} dbname={} user={} password={} port={}".format(host, db_name,user,password,port))
cur = conn.cursor()
print("connected")

create_table_query = "create table if not exists test_data (col_1 varchar, col_2 varchar)"
cur.execute(create_table_query)
print('table created')

conn.commit()
print('committed')
```

This code executes successfully for me. But when I use the query editor on redshift, I am unable to view or select from `test_data` table. It throws out the error: ERROR:  Table "test_data" does not exist.
Why could this be?

Comment: Is your Redshift console in the US-East-1 (N.Virginia) region? Can you select the Database and Schema to the left of the Editor?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, it is on the US-East-1 region. Also, I can see the db and schemas to the left of the editor. [here](https://ibb.co/XLBc96f) is a screenshot

Comment: And is the `test_data` table showing underneath that (near the `event` and `listing` tables)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Surprisingly I can see it now, though I am yet to figure out what was wrong earlier.

Comment: Was your console session in a transaction?  If so Redshift will preserve the DB state at the point the transaction was started for that session until commit or rollback

Comment: @BillWeiner - Tried re-running my original file. Most probably that was the issue. The original file had a copy statement at the end of the file before the commit. Probably the copy command failed during my run and the commit never got executed. :(

Comment: Definitely possible.  But even if it succeeded it is possible that the observing session was looking at older version of data and just needed a COMMIT or ROLLBACK to catch up

Comment: @BillWeiner As part of trying out the above, I could reproduce the issue again. I realised that was on Redshift Query Editor V2 when I first observed the problem. Here, even after executing a commit, I am unable to view the table. (screenshots [before](https://ibb.co/L6YN4Gn) and [after](https://ibb.co/41ZSsT9) commit) Looks like the problem is related to the editor.

Comment: Could be.  I like to know the bench I'm using interfaces w/ Redshift (sessions, transactions, etc) and I'm not very familiar with the query editor.  Do things work predictably with a non-browser-based bench?